# Have any scholar like Dr.Gopinarh Kaviraj written any book about Nayanars and Saiva Siddhanta?

Tags: shiva, shaiva-siddhanta, nayanar

If yes can you tell me the name of the book?
Also which language It was written in?
Can you give me a pdf link of it?
Thanks for help.

Comment: "Scholar like Dr. Gopinath Kaviraj." What is the similarity you are looking for?

Comment: I mean Dr.Gopinath or Any great scholar written a book about Nayanar and Saiva Siddhanta